How can I import a env file from os to jupyter notebook?
I am not able to import my API key to my jupyter notebook which is on web browser, I tried importing it shows None. What do I do?
I was excepting the API key to be printed as that is what I tried importing, but it printed None.

Regarding the "web browser", is the code you are executing and the .env file located on the same machine?

.env is located on my local machine , but the jupyter notebook is a copy of another jupyter notebook , its from a online AI course im doing , i wanted to use my open api key but it is im my local machine

But is the notebook on your local machine (accessed via a file:// or http://localhost/... URL, for example), or is it still on a remote server? The remote notebook isn't going to have access to a locally-stored .env via via the web browser, at least not with the dotenv library.

Thank you so much for you help , I ran it on my VS code and downloaded the dependencies and it worked.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I am 90% sure this is a question with an answer somewhere else, but here you go:
# os for accessing the env
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv
# loading variables from .env file
load_dotenv() # pass a path if it's not a .env in the current working directory 
 
# accessing and printing value
print(os.getenv("VARIABLE_NAME"))

this is if your jupyter is being executed locally. The browser is merely where you look at the notebook, the actual calculation/execution of python could be any place. So if you are using e.g. google collab it is running on googles computers and you need to upload it to the instance.
For debugging you can check where python is executed by printing the current working directory and it's contents
import os
cwd=os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
print(os.listdir(cwd))

Is the path what you expect? is the content of the folder a folder on your computer?

OP's problem seems to be that the code isn't executing on the same machine that stores the .env file.

@chepner thanks you beat me to it. just added a short section how a jupyter notebook is not running inside the browser

I had second thoughts (I think you could be executing a local notebook via the web interface, right?), so I've copied my comment on the question to for clarification.

@chepner you are right , I was doing a project from deeplearning AI and made a copy of the notebook project so it opened on the web, I wanted to use my api key, i had saved it to my local env , and tried to import but it showed none
